# Multiple pretrained networks in Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe, nvidia-digits

Is there a simple way (e.g. without modifying [caffe](/questions/tagged/caffe) code) to load wights from multiple pretrained networks into one network? The network contains some layers with same dimensions and names as both pretrained networks.

I am trying to achieve this using NVidia DIGITS and Caffe.

**EDIT**: I thought it wouldn't be possible to do it directly from DIGITS, as confirmed by answers. Can anyone suggest a simple way to modify the DIGITS code to be able to select multiple pretrained networks? I checked the code a bit, and thought the [training script](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/f9ad5ced48fa49c677066f1d6b315601ccfae163/digits/model/tasks/train.py#L49) would be a good place to start, but I don't have in-depth knowledge of Caffe, so I'm not sure what the best/quickest way to achieve this would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Shai suggested, there was no way of doing this, so I decided to clone the official repository and make the appropriate changes. I changed the code so that multiple pretrained networks can be loaded by using a colon as separator.

I created a pull request on the official repository and my changes were then merged with the main branch of DIGITS, meaning it is now possible to use this functionality in DIGITS.

Comment: have you made similar pull request to the BVLC/caffe repository?

Comment: You can do this with `caffe` using the `--weights` parameter separating different networks with commas.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no straight forward way of doing so.
However, you can use [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) to load the pretrained models and manually assign their weights to the target net. Once you have a single net with all the weights initialized according to the various pretrained models, you can save it and use it as a single pretrained model for the rest of your work.

Comment: this is how to do it...a NN model is just a bunch of weights so all you need to do is copy them over and save it.  good luck though...if you copy layers from different nets they may not play well together. And digits is pretty high level...you'll need to drop into python or c++ to get it done.

Comment: Is there an easy way to incorporate this into the DIGITS code (I edited the question)?

Comment: @IgorŠevo if you are going to try this trick many times, you may consider altering the training script of DIGITS. However, I think if you are going to do this only once or twice you'd better do it manually using "net surgery".

Comment: I'm probably going to do this multiple times with different architectures, so I'm going to need something a bit more high-level.

Comment: @IgorŠevo well, I think the first step to modify the training script is to programmatically do this modification once in python. Can you make it work once?

Comment: I could probably use the "net surgery" you suggested and add modified code to the DIGITS training script. I was hopping Caffe would expose some API for loading weights from a different network.